# SPRING XD -SQOOP JOB FAILED due to invalid arguments

Tags: java, hdfs, sqoop, spring-xd

We are trying to ingest data from  sql server to hdfs using sqoop job as a module of spring xd.

When I tried running the following command using xd - shell of spring xd tool:

```
sqoop --command=import --args='--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/mydb'  
--username root --password p@ss --query select * from tablename  
--target-dir /path/to/hdfs/file'
```

I get the following error while launching the job from spring xd shell as a sqoop job:

**sqoop.errors**

```
Try --help for usage instructions.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Sqoop failed - return code 1
at org.springframework.xd.sqoop.SqoopRunner.main(SqoopRunner.java:81)
```

**more errors**

```
19:38:40,556 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Error parsing arguments for import:
19:38:40,556 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: '--connect
19:38:40,556 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/mydb'
19:38:40,556 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: --username
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: root
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: --password
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: p@ss
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: --query
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: select
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: *
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: from
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: tablename
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: --target-dir
19:38:40,557 ERROR main tool.BaseSqoopTool - Unrecognized argument: /path/to/hdfs/file'
```

**exit description :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Step execution failed - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Sqoop failed - return code 1
at org.springframework.batch.step.tasklet.x.AbstractProcessBuilderTasklet.execute(AbstractProcessBuilderTasklet.java:209)
```

I also tried putting `=` after arguments but obtained same results.

Why?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In its current state your question is unanswerable; please try to edit it for readability and add some more details about what you have tried.

Comment: i added most of  info. is that readable ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got single quotes inside of single quotes, which is splitting your command into

```
sqoop --command=import --args='--connect '
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/mydb
'--username root --password p@ss --query select * from tablename --target-dir /path/to/hdfs/file'
```

since `--connect` isn't a valid argument by itself, you're getting an error.

You can either escape the single quotes, like this: `sqoop --command=import --args='--connect \'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/mydb\' --username root --password p@ss --query select * from tablename --target-dir /path/to/hdfs/file'`

or you should also be able to use double quotes around the `args` section instead of single quotes, like this: `sqoop --command=import --args="--connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/mydb' --username root --password p@ss --query select * from tablename --target-dir /path/to/hdfs/file"`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying my stream is now accepting the argument but now it is showing other error of invalid object. This is a common error and maybe a bug in sqoop.

    0:59:07,087 INFO main manager.SqlManager - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [dbo.table_name] AS t WHERE 1=0
    10:59:07,128 ERROR main manager.SqlManager - Error executing statement:     com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'dbo.table_name'.

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sqoop-user/201310.mbox/%3C20131031164223.GE5190@localhost%3E

Comment: 2015-04-18 06:18:17,604 1.1.0.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-3 sqoop.SqoopTasklet - Sqoop err: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Sqoop failed - return code 1
2015-04-18 06:18:17,604 1.1.0.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-3 sqoop.SqoopTasklet - Sqoop err: at org.springframework.xd.sqoop.SqoopRunner.main(SqoopRunner.java:81)

Comment: continued with more error -- 2015-04-18 06:18:17,608 1.1.0.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-3 step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step tasklet in job sqooptest5
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Step execution failed - 06:18:16,959 INFO main mapreduce.Job - Job job_1425378609799_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1425378609799_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1425378609799_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-launch: